# Lebesgue measure of an uncountable union

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be an injective but not surjective mapping from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ (which will be defined in the supplement below).

Fix an intervel $I\subseteq [0,1]$.

For each $\omega \in I$, we define $x_\omega :=f(\omega)$.

We will later define a set $Q_\omega$ which depends on $\omega$ (see the supplement below for definition which is too long to be written here), which may NOT be a proper subset of $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$.

Let us denote the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ by $m$.

Then it is clear that $m(I)=|I|$, where $|I|$ means the length of $I$.

**My question** is how to calculate $$m(\cup_{\omega\in I} \{\{f(\omega)\}\cup Q_\omega\})\,?$$

I really want $m(\cup_{\omega\in I} \{\{f(\omega)\}\cup Q_\omega\})=m(I)=|I|.$

---

**Supplement (definition of $f$):**

We do have an explicit definition of $f$.

Fix $\omega \in [0,1]$. We have a unique binary expansion: $$\omega=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \beta_n 2^{-n},\,\text{where } \beta_n=\beta_n(\omega) \text{ which is either 0 or 1 and }\sum \beta_n = \infty.$$

There are a lot of bijections between $\mathbb N^2$ and $\mathbb N$. We just pick an arbitrary one, denoted by $g$, where $g:\mathbb N^2 \to \mathbb N$.

Fix $j\in \mathbb N$. Then $g_j(n):=g[(n,j)]$ defines an injective but not surjective map from $\mathbb N$ to itself.

We can therefore define $\omega_j=\omega_j(\omega):=\sum_{n\in \mathbb N} \beta_{g(n,j)}2^{-n}$.

[*Observation:* Given a fixed $\omega\in I$, we have its binary expansion, which determines all $\beta_n$'s. Fix $j\in \mathbb N$, $\{g[(n,j)]| n\in \mathbb N\}$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb N$, which means that, $\omega_j$ is defined by only using some of $\beta_n$'s. For those $n$ which are not used in defining $\omega_j$, even if we alter the values of the corresponding $\beta_n$ resulting in new $\tilde{\omega}$, we still have $\omega_j(\omega)=\omega_j(\tilde{\omega})$.]

For any $y\in [0,1]$, $\omega_j^{-1}(\{y\})$ consists of many points, each of which is in $[0,1]$ and has a unique binary expression $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \gamma_n 2^{-n}$. We define $f(\omega)$ as the unique element in $\omega_j^{-1}(\{\omega\})$ whose binary expression has the most $\gamma$'s which are $0$.

Then $f$ is defined as an injective but not surjective mapping from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$.

---

**Supplement (definition of $Q_\omega$):**

Fix $\omega$ and $j$ as above.

As we mentioned in the *Observation* above, $\omega_j$ is defined by only using some of $\beta_n$'s, which are coefficients in the binary expansion of $\omega$. For those $n$ which are not used in defining $\omega_j$, even if we alter the values of the corresponding $\beta_n$ resulting in new $\tilde{\omega}$, we still have $\omega_j(\omega)=\omega_j(\tilde{\omega})$.

Also recall that, we define $f(\omega)$ as the unique element in $\omega_j^{-1}(\{\omega\})$ whose binary expression has the most $\gamma$'s which are $0$. Note that there are at most countably infinitely many $0$'s as the coefficients in the binary expansion of $f(\omega)$. If we alter one of these $0$'s(i.e. change one of these $0$'s to $1$'s), then the resulted number, say $k$, represented by this new binary expansion is still in $\omega_j^{-1}(\{\omega\})$. Indeed more generally, if we alter any finite numbers of these $0$'s, the resulted number is still in $\omega_j^{-1}(\{\omega\})$. Define $Q_\omega$ as the set of all of numbers obtained by altering the coefficients in the binary expansion of $f(\omega)$ in this way. Note that $Q_\omega$ may contain irrationals(in the case where $\omega$ is irrational). One can see that $\omega_j^{-1}(\{\omega\})=Q_\omega\cup f(\omega)$.

**My question then can be rephrased as follows.**

How to calculate $$m(\cup_{\omega\in I}\omega_j^{-1}(\{\omega\}))\,?$$

I really want $m(\cup_{\omega\in I}\omega_j^{-1}(\{\omega\}))=m(I)=|I|.$

Comment: It seems that $Q_x$ is not clearly defined.

Comment: I have two things to note. First, I think you should denote $Q_x$ by $Q_{\alpha}$ instead, since $\alpha$ is what it depends on.

Comment: Second, there may be a simpler way to represent your union. Since $0 \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $x_\alpha \in [0,1]$, you can note that $\{x_\alpha\} \cup (Q_\alpha + x_\alpha) = Q_\alpha + x_\alpha$. Moreover, you have $Q_\alpha + x_\alpha = \{y \in [0,1] : y-x_\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}\}$, and this seems like an easier set to conceptualize. If you let this be, say $R_\alpha$, then what you want to know is the measure of $\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} R_\alpha$.

Comment: @Sambo Thanks for the comments and the answer. Yes, there are some problems in my statement. I was trying to simplify my setting but it turned out that I didn't simplify it well. I will edit my post to re-define $Q_\alpha$ now and you may come back to see the updates later.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Thanks for the comment. I have edited the post and defined $Q_\omega$ properly(I have changed the notation).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question completely, but it does show that your hypothesis (that the measure equals $m(I)$ is false.

**Fact: if $f(I)$ contains an interval, then the union is $[0,1]$.**

**Proof.** Let $J$ be an interval contained in $f(I)$. Let $y \in [0,1]$; I will show that $y \in \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} (Q_\alpha + x_\alpha)$.

Since $J$ is an interval, $J-y$ must be too, which means it contains a rational number $q$. Then $q+y \in J$, and since $J \subseteq f(I)$, we know that $q+y = f(\alpha) = x_\alpha$ for some $\alpha \in I$. Then $y = x_\alpha + (-q)$.

So, we have picked $-q \in \mathbb{Q}$. We know that $(-q) + x_\alpha = y \in [0,1]$, so $(-q) \in Q_\alpha$, and thus $y = x_\alpha + (-q) \in x_\alpha + Q_\alpha \subseteq \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} (Q_\alpha + x_\alpha)$. This is what we wanted to show.

The reverse inclusion is trivial. So, the inclusion is indeed $[0,1]$. $\square$

---

This can happen if, for instance, $f(\alpha) = \alpha/2$ and $I$ is any interval.

Comment: Thanks for the post. The function $f$ doesn't really preserve orders of numbers, i.e. we may have $f(a)<f(b)$ or $f(a)>f(b)$ for different $a,b$ s.t. $a<b$. And by the definition of $f$(cf. the statement of the OP), it is unlikely that $f(I)$ will contain an interval.